# Yii2 activequery display data to view

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to query data from specific table from database and display it in my view.

From my Controller function.

```
 public function actionViewPds()
{ 
    //$model = new User();
    $query= new \yii\db\Query;
    $provider=new  ArrayDataProvider([
      'allModels'=>$query->from('{{%tbl_family_background}}')->orderBy('[[nfamily_id]]')->all(),
    ]);

    return $this->render('view-pds',[
      'model' => $provider,
    ]);
}
```

And in my view, where I want to display the data.

```
<?php $model->nfamily_id;?>
```

and my error

```
Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
```

Getting unknown property: yii\data\ArrayDataProvider::nfamily_id

Comment: You're confusing data provider (collection of models) with model.

Answer (score 0):

`$model` in your view is an instance of `ArrayDataProvider`. To access the models you will need to use the property [`allModels`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider#$allModels-detail). There are all the models your query returned.

But in that case you might just drop the data provider completely, since you're not really using it, it seems.

So in the controller:

```php
return $this->render('view-pds',[
    'models' => $query->from('{{%tbl_family_background}}')->orderBy('[[nfamily_id]]')->all(),
]);
```

In the view:

```php
foreach($models as $model) {
    echo $model['nfamily_id'] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank You @HotRob, But I still got an error.  Trying to get property 'nfamily_id' of non-object

Comment: But when I try to display the data from $models using   var_dump($model);, It display the data like this. array(1) { [0]=> array(12) { ["nfamily_id"]=> int(1) ["csurname"]=> string(7) "sample8" ["cfname"]=> string(7) "sample8" ["cmname"]=> string(7) "sample8" ["csuffix"]=> string(0) "" ["coccupation"]=> string(7) "sample8" ["cemployer_busines_name"]=> string(7) "sample8" ["cbusiness_address"]=> string(7) "sample8" ["ctelephone_number"]=> string(6) "000000" ["crelationship"]=> string(6) "Mother" ["dbirthdate"]=> string(10) "2019-01-21" ["id"]=> int(1) } } ,

Comment: Querying this way you get array of arrays, not objects. Try

echo $model['"nfamily_id"] . "\n";

Comment: In these cases you could use `var_dump` or Yii's own [`VarDumper`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-vardumper) to see what the variable looks like.